# Eclipse SVN synchronize problem

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, subclipse

We changed our SVN machine because of a hardware problem. We established the same environment from back-up to another machine.

Now Subversion seems to work properly, I can update, commit and browse from Tortoise Client.

But in Eclipse problem exist for Synchronize command (subclipse plugin). I can browse and commit from Eclipse too.

I tried to change SVN interface (from JavaHL to SVNKit), svn cleanup and upgrade subclipse plugin, but nothing helps.

JavaHL and SVNKit gives different errors.

```
**Error when use JavaHL**
Problems reported while synchronizing SVNStatusSubscriber. 0 of 1 resources were synchronized.
  An error occurred synchronizing /ChemOrbis: Error getting status for resource P/ChemOrbis org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed
svn: REPORT of '/svn/ChemOrbis/!svn/vcc/default': 200 OK (http://svn.treda.net)

    Error getting status for resource P/ChemOrbis org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed
svn: REPORT of '/svn/ChemOrbis/!svn/vcc/default': 200 OK (http://svn.treda.net)

      org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed
svn: REPORT of '/svn/ChemOrbis/!svn/vcc/default': 200 OK (http://svn.treda.net)

      org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed
svn: REPORT of '/svn/ChemOrbis/!svn/vcc/default': 200 OK (http://svn.treda.net)


**Error when use SVNKit**
Problems reported while synchronizing SVNStatusSubscriber. 0 of 1 resources were synchronized.
  An error occurred synchronizing /ChemOrbis: Error getting status for resource P/ChemOrbis org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: Processing REPORT request response failed: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. (/svn/ChemOrbis/!svn/vcc/default) 
svn: REPORT request failed on '/svn/ChemOrbis/!svn/vcc/default'
    Error getting status for resource P/ChemOrbis org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: Processing REPORT request response failed: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. (/svn/ChemOrbis/!svn/vcc/default) 
svn: REPORT request failed on '/svn/ChemOrbis/!svn/vcc/default'
      org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: Processing REPORT request response failed: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. (/svn/ChemOrbis/!svn/vcc/default) 
svn: REPORT request failed on '/svn/ChemOrbis/!svn/vcc/default'
      org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: Processing REPORT request response failed: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. (/svn/ChemOrbis/!svn/vcc/default) 
svn: REPORT request failed on '/svn/ChemOrbis/!svn/vcc/default'
```

Comment: Do you use 64Bit Version of Eclipse?
I remember on unresolved Problems in this constellation.
32Bit Version works fine with subclipse.

Answer (score 20):

I'd try a clean-up - right click on the project, then select Team/Cleanup...

In a lot of cases this helps to solve synchronize problems.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem for me.  I had to quit and restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Clean all svn passwords saved in eclipse. Try do not save any svn passwords in eclipse.

Then in .subversion/config file change this:

```
[auth]
# other config options
# you should reset password stores here
password-stores =
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Clean the workspace
2. Delete the project from workspace
3. Re-import the project from SVN

This has solved the problem for me.

Comment: what if  you have some changes to commit?

Answer (score 0):

It happened twice For me.
Once I resolved Like this --
I made a backup file with my changes .
I closed my eclipse -> go into the prject in windows explorer - > Go to the file in conflict -> right click -> SVN -> Revert.
Now I started eclipse -> put back my changes and it worked.

Second time it happened --
That did not help.
So, I had to delete the project on my eclipse workspace, and checked out the project from SVN  and it worked.

-Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade with Team.....>Upgrade 
Then you will not see those errors.